# How to find out which packages have been installed from .deb files

Tags: package-management, synaptic

I've previously installed some packages from .deb files using gdeb. I've now forgotten which ones. As I will soon update from Precise to Trusty, I'd like to uninstall them & go back to the standard Precise repo ones before upgrading: then I will find out if apps dependent on these packages work before considering installing them from .deb files. I think that I remember that this could be done using Synaptic. Anybody know how?

Answer (score 1):

Open Synaptic, click `Status` and choose `Installed (local)`.

Also check your history: `File` -> `History`

[image]

Also in Software Center at Installed - the `Unknown` category